# Parse JSON data into a variable assignment format

Tags: json, shell, jq

I am trying to parse JSON data into variable format

```
[
  {
    "Name" : "a",
    "Value" : "1"
  },
  {
    "Name" : "b",
    "Value" : "2"
  },
  {
    "Name" : "c",
    "Value" : "3"
  }
]
```

output should be like

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

This is what I tried, but it is not giving the expected result:

```
jq '.[].Value' file.txt
```

Comment: what did you try with `jq`? You are probably very close!

Comment: jq .[].Name file.txt
or 
jq .[].Value file.txt

this is printing key, valye in one go but how to assign value to key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON with UNIX tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)

Comment: cat file.txt |jq -r  '.[].Name,.[].Value'

I have tried this. Now how can I assign value to key in output?

Answer (score 5):

Since you're only printing out two values, it might just be easier to print out the strings directly.

```
$ jq -r '.[] | "\(.Name)=\(.Value)"' file.txt
```

Comment: Better than my attempt using a list and then join. I never knew that this kind if string interpolation is possible using jq.

Comment: Also `... | .Name + "=" + .Value`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following `jq` command:

```
jq -r '.[]|[.Name,.Value]|join("=")' file.json
```

Output:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

Comment: This answer better represents the expected output, though my answer might be useful if the json format needs preservation through other modifications. Feel free to copy mine into your answer to provide an all-encompassing solution (then I'll delete mine).

Comment: @bishop I see your point, but let me keep it simple. Readers will still have your answer as an alternative in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

Using `jq`:

```
jq 'map({(.Name):.Value})|add|.//={}' < data.json
```

Produces:

```
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": "2",
  "c": "3"
}
```

If you have `jq` version 1.5+, you can use `from_entries` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This does it

```
python3 -c 'import json; print("\n".join(["{}={}".format(x["Value"], x["Name"]) for x in json.load(open("file.json"))]))'
```

result

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

Comment: A Python solution would not be adequate here, he was specifically looking for a jq solution.